# How to uncheck no data value option in Python

Tags: qgis, python, nodata

I have been using QGIS to perform raster calculations, which have required me to uncheck the `no data value` box.

I am now trying to accomplish all these steps in Python, and was wondering does anyone know how to uncheck the no data value box via python??

If its not unchecked then my raster calculations won't perform correctly

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to disable nodata value I believe it means that the nodata is set wrong in the source data. Therefore I suggest to correct the source data with gdal_edit.py https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_edit.html#cmdoption-unsetnodata and then you do not need to use any extra settings with QGIS nor with Python.

> -**unsetnodata** Remove existing nodata values.